# Can Variance be replaced by absolute value in this optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

Initially I modeled my objective function as

$$\arg \min \operatorname{Var}(f(x),g(x)) + \operatorname{Var}(c(x),d(x)) + \cdots$$

where $f$, $g$, $c$, $x$ are linear functions.

To be able to solve the problem with linear solvers I have change the problem as follows ($\operatorname{abs}$ stands for absolute value):

$$\arg \min\; \operatorname{abs}(f(x)-g(x)) + \operatorname{abs}(c(x)-d(x)) + \cdots$$

Is this form correct and has the same meaning as the first model?

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by $\mbox{Var}(f(x),g(x))$, and there aren't any random variables or data mentioned in your question, so it's very hard to make any sense of the question.  What do you mean by $\mbox{Var}$?

Comment: I imagine you meant "absolute value" and not "abstract value".

Comment: Cross-posted: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302975/can-variance-be-replaced-by-absolute-value-in-this-objective-function)  and [Mathematics SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415371/can-variance-be-replaced-by-absolute-value-in-this-objective-function). Cross-posting is discouraged, since you are not respecting the time of people that answer to you in each site.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing much about your question it is hard to answer more specifically. So first and foremost - no. These are not equivalent. Minimizing variangce will generally make you converge to some kind of sample **mean**, whereas minimizing absolute deviation would (generally) make you find some kind of sample **median**.

A generally favourable property of sample means is fast convergence (at least, when compared to median). A good property of sample medians is robustness - insensitivity to outliers.